# Store formulas as an element of an array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, functional-programming

(* I don't know programming in Matlab. It is just a general question about Matlab language. *)

In Excel, we can store a formula in a cell. For instance, if `A2` contains a formula `= A1+10`, the re-evaluation of `A2` returns `30` when the value of `A1` is `20`.

My question is, is there a similar mechanism in matlab? That said, can we specify a `formula` in a element of an array in Matlab, so that we can re-evaluate the array later?

**Edit 1:**
Following the comment of @rayryeng I try to make an example to illustrate the concept... Actually, this is exactly what spreadsheet languages such as Excel can do.

So my question is, is there a mechanism that permits the following in Matlab? (Note that the following syntax is just symbolic)

```
>> B = [1 2; B{1,1}+2 4] // store some values and a formula in the array

B =

     1     2
     3     4

>> B{1,1} = 10 // change the value of one cell

B =

     10     2
     3      4

>> EVAL(B) // there is a re-evaluation command to re-calculate all the cells

ans =

     10     2
     13     4
```

Comment: No, it's not really how any programming language works. In MATLAB you have [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html) and [scripts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/scripts.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully I'm understanding what you want correctly, but the answer is indeed yes.  You can store "formulas" in a cell array where each element is a handle or an anonymous function.

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
formulae = {@(x) x+10, @sin, @cos, @(x) x / 3};
```

The syntax `@` denotes a function handle and the `(x)` denote that this is an anonymous function with the input variable `x`.  The first cell element provides a function that adds 10 to every value that goes into it, the second and third parameters are handles to `sin` and `cos`, so these act like those trigonometric functions.  The last handle divides every value that goes into it by 3.

To demonstrate, let's create a small array, then go through each formula and apply each of them to the small array:

```
>> formulae = {@(x) x+10, @sin, @cos, @(x) x / 3};
>> A = [1 2; 3 4]

A =

     1     2
     3     4

>> formulae{1}(A)

ans =

    11    12
    13    14

>> formulae{2}(A)

ans =

    0.8415    0.9093
    0.1411   -0.7568

>> formulae{3}(A)

ans =

    0.5403   -0.4161
   -0.9900   -0.6536

>> formulae{4}(A)

ans =

    0.3333    0.6667
    1.0000    1.3333
```

We first create the formulae, then create a small 2 x 2 matrix of `[1 2; 3 4]`.  After, we access each formula's cell, then put in the input `A` into the function and we get what you see.

---

However, when you're starting out, start with actually declaring functions in function scripts.... don't use this kind of style of programming for practical applications.  It makes your code less readable.  For example, doing `sin(A)` is much more readable than `formula{2}(A)`.  People reading your code have to remember what position in the array corresponds to what formula you are applying to each element in the input.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed comment... I updated my OP. You show that we can store formulas in an array (ie, `formulae`), so that responds to my question (with answer `Yes`). But i just realise that it is still different from what we can do in Excel: it seems that we cannot specify a cell in a formula. Eg, every formula has to be related to constant or the variable `x`, it can not be related to another formula (we cannot write `=B{1,1}+2` in a formula). Am I correct?

Comment: @rayryeng you actually can do it I think, see the bottom of my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33144578/1011724. However, it's probably not the most idiomatic way of doing things in Matlab and the OP can most like refactor their code to a much simpler equivalent solution