# Apply a cell array of functions to a value

Tags: matlab

I define a cell array that contains values and functions:

```
>> A = {1, 2, 3; @(x) x+5, @(x) x+10, 5}

A = 

    [    1]    [     2]    [3]
    @(x)x+5    @(x)x+10    [5]
```

Does anyone know how to apply this cell array to a value? For instance, when `x = 2`, the application returns another cell array:

```
    [ 1]    [     2]    [3]
    [ 7]    [    12]    [5]
```

Comment: what is the first row (`1,2,3`) used for? are these just "constant" functions?

Comment: Yes, they are just "constant" functions...

Comment: @SoftTimur in Matlab, call this a cell array not a tuple. Can't you make the constants just `@(x)(2)` for example so that you have all the same data type?

Comment: Sure, you can, for me `2` is equivalent to `@(x)(2)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your constants as functions:

```
A = {@(x)1, @(x)2, @(x)3; @(x) x+5, @(x) x+10, @(x)5}
```

now use `cellfun`:

```
k = 2;
cellfun(@(x)x(k),A)
```

Also note that if you want to apply multiple `k` values at once (e.g. `k = 1:5`) you will need to edit your constant functions in `A` from this form `@(x) n` to something like `@(x) n*ones(size(x))` and then change the `cellfun` call to:

```
cellfun(@(x)x(k),A, 'uni',0)
```

---

To answer the question from your comments:

> is it possible to refer to other cells in a function in a cell array?
>   For instance, can we define something like  `A = {@(x)1, @(x)2, the 1st cell + the 2nd cell, @(x)4}`?

You define `A` as follows:

```
A = {@(x)1, @(x)2, @(x)(A{1}(x)+A{2}(x)), @(x)4}
```

Comment: I just want to make sure... is it possible to refer to other cells in a function in a cell array? For instance, can we define something like `A = {@(x)1, @(x)2, the 1st cell + the 2nd cell, @(x)4}`?

Comment: @SoftTimur see my edit, you actually can do what you were asking in that other question. But I think you're going down a rabbit hole here, Matlab is not Excel. You can probably achieve exactly what you are getting in Excel in a simpler more idiomatic Matlab way rather than trying to duplicate Excel's "syntax" in another language. Rather learn the Matlab way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be better to define the cell-array/function thingie like this:

```
A = @(x) {1, 2, 3; x+5, x+10, 5};
```

Then you can apply it by simpliy doing

```
A(2)
```

---

Maybe you can even use normal matrices instead of cell array here:

```
A = @(x) [1, 2, 3; x+5, x+10, 5];
```

Comment: I see... In this case, there is no syntax to refer to other cells as we discussed in another answer, right?

Comment: You can using `paren = @(x, varargin) x(varargin{:});` and then you can access the element `k` by doing `paren(A(x),3)`, if you use matrices. If you use a cell-array you'd use `curly = @(x, varargin) x{varargin{:}};` in the same way. See [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/)