# Vectrorized Calls of function handles, which are stored in a cell

Tags: matlab

I would like to know if there is a way to vectorize the calls of different function handles, which are stored in a cell array and have of course input values themselves. I basically have a model, which looks like:

```
    MyModel=cell(2,1);
    MyModel{1}=@(a,b) a+b;
    MyModel{2}=@(a,b) a-b;
    a=[1,2];
    b=[2,1];
    ModelNumber=[1,2];
```

Now I would like to call `MyModel{ModelNumber(1)}` at `a(1)` and `b(1)` and `MyModel{ModelNumber(2)}` at `a(2)` and `b(2)`. Of course it can be done with a `for` loop. However, the real thing will take a lot of time, if I use a loop. So is there a way to vectorize the problem in a way that something like

```
    MyModel{ModelNumber(:)}(a(:),b(:))
```

works? I already looked at cellfun, but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks in advance!
Ingo

Comment: There is probably no reason to use cellfun here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I cannot see where structfun may help.  Both, `cellfun` and `structfun` apply a function to all elements of a cell or struct. But i have a load of different functions.

Comment: @ingo: your original title had a typo in it, there you wrote functions in a struct while the question is about functions in cells. I corrected the title. Structfun probably won't help here.

Comment: @Daniel, Oh sorry, of course I was talking about cells,thanks

Comment: @Daniel `cellfun` is just nice as shorthand. This doesn't look like performance is a major issue.

Comment: @Ingo try using `cellfun` like so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33144578/1011724

Comment: @dan: performance seems to be the issue here "However, the real thing will take a lot of time, if I use a loop.".  Don't see cellfun solving this.

Comment: @Daniel I did not read properly. Sure, `cellfun` is not going to outperform a loop!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, simply using `cellfun` won't increase the performance over a simple for loop. Thus a for loop is the best solution for the generic case you described above.

I would expect a good performance from a for loop in this case, thus if your solution is to slow you may put it into the question and we will see if it could be improved.